# Can't Add More Than One New Trigger to Script Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to make both of these new triggers a part of my existing function.  I at one time got one to work, and when I added the second, both triggers would not be created at the same time.  Help please.

```
  // Trigger every 15 Minutes
ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyPriceData')
.timeBased()
.everyMinutes(2)
.create(); 

 //Delete Trigger after Market Closes
ScriptApp.newTrigger("delete_Triggers")
  .timeBased()
  .after(6 * 60 * 1000)
  .create();
```

Existing code is:

```
 function CopyLive1() {

 var date = new Date();  
 var day = date.getDay();
 var hrs = date.getHours();
 var min = date.getMinutes();
 if ((hrs >= 15) && (hrs <= 15) && (min >= 46) && (min <= 46)) {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 // Get more recent closing prices

 var closePriceRange = sheet.getRange("F4");
 var prevClosePriceRange = sheet.getRange("F5");

 var closePrice = closePriceRange.getValue();
 var prevClosePrice = prevClosePriceRange.getValue();

// Check if price data has updated. If so create new row and copy price data.

 if (closePrice != prevClosePrice)

  {sheet.insertRowsAfter(4, 1);

  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange("B4:G4");

  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange("B5:G5"), {contentsOnly:true});
  }
  sheet.deleteRow(1825);    
  }

  }
```